# Klocwork complains resource leak for an object that is not marked as disposable

Tags: c#, klocwork

I have a class that was wrongly marked as IDisposable. When Klocwork complained about a resource leak for objects of that class, I have removed IDisposable implementation from that class. When I re-run Klocwork analysis, it still complains about same resource leak. I was expecting the errors to go away.

Do I need to do anything  more? Please help.

Comment: A few more details would help. Like the exact warning message + the indicated code.

Comment: What version of Klocwork are you using? C# analysis support was greatly enhanced in version 10.1 and the latest 10.2.1 version.